# AdMob Native Ads crash my app

Tags: android, admob, ads

I got this crash a lot, especially after a displayed ad gets destroyed:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean java.util.Map.containsKey(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.formats.v.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:357)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.formats.w.run(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:3038)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5373)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
```

And it's very unfortunate because it crashes the app completely...Now Google promised to fix this but I'm wondering if anyone had the same issue and found a way to circumvent it. At least to prevent a complete crash because my users are not happy with this.

Comment: Why don't you put this into a try-catch?

Comment: This is not directly called, but part of lifecycle and Admob handles it itself. You cant reach this code directly.